# updating Beans marked as RefreshScope

Tags: refresh, reload, spring-cloud-config

Here is my scenario:
My micro service gets notified about some changes of its configuration from the central conf server. It can be partial update, or a full.
I use @RefreshScope mark on relevant beans. The question is how to update marked beans, I mean reload them. 
Just to clarify: From Spring Cloud I use only RefreshScope.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add dependency `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator` in your project.
2. Refreshing configuration via call `refresh` endpoint.

For example, you configure your management endpoint like below. `curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/manage/refresh` will trigger refreshing changed configuration.

`management:
  context-path: /manage
  port: 8001
  security.enabled: false`

Comment: Thanks. But it do not solve my problem. It will refresh if my config is in "repository", however my case is different, because my app gets changed parameters and from now on it should update them in all relevant places. May be should I update firstly env, and after that call to refresh ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have different components that are affected by changes, then it's good to keep your configurations on repository and then you can add a publish-subscribe model for refreshing context in which all the affected components are to subscribe to an event that is published by your repository as a result of configurations change.

And for refreshing context we have two options:

1. Hit refresh endpoint of your app by a post request.
2. Get RefreshEndpoint bean by autowiring it, then apply refreshEndpoint.refresh(). This will refresh context at runtime.

In both solutions mark the beans of interest by @RefreshScope.